# Why is my Django template not displaying on my webpage?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have two classes in my models, two defs in views and one template in one app. Just one of the functions doesn't work properly. Everything else works fine.

I double checked everything but didn't find the issue. Below the code:

Models

```
from django.db import models

class BildTextMarkt(models.Model):

    fotomarkt = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

    text = models.TextField(blank=True, max_length= 512)
```

views

```
def bildtextmarkt(request):

    all_maerkte = BildTextMarkt.objects.all()

    context = {'my_maerkte':all_maerkte}

    return render(request, 'maerkte/maerkte.html', context)
```

templates

```
{% for maerkte2 in my_maerkte %}
      <div class="bild">{{ maerkte2.fotomarkt }}</div>
      <div>{{ maerkte2.text }} </div>
    
{% endfor %}
```

Thank you for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

the imagefield item in the template should be

```
<img src="{{ maerkte2.fotomarkt.url }}">
```